# CC removed in mac os x

Tags: macos, terminal, cc

I accidentally removed cc from /usr/bin/ in my iMac while trying to remove a softlink. And I do not have a backup. 
How do I get it back? Can I get it back? 
Any help at all would be appreciated.
(Horrible mistake made out of haste and anticipation :( )

Comment: On my OSX Yosemite, `cc` is just a link to `clang`, so you would do `cd /usr/bin` and then type `ln -s clang cc` if your OS is similar. Or click that `Time Machine` icon...

Comment: Yes I did do that. I forgot it was just a soft link to clang. But I assumed that if I did do cc -v in terminal I would have seen clang's version data to be displayed. But all I get in bash: command not found prompt. Shouldn't bash know cc is a command? Was it never a command? (albeit still a soft link)

Comment: You may need to do `hash -r` or logout and back in.